# Modifying Auto-Clicker Python Code to Use Mouse Button to Start and Stop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I'm using the code from this website, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-a-python-auto-clicker/, and I feel like I have it setup correctly but I get some strange errors when I trigger the auto clicker. I'm modifying it to use a button on my mouse as the start and stop button instead of keys on my keyboard. I actually don't even need pynput.keyboard. My script runs but I get these errors when I press the button on my mouse:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
# importing time and threading
import time
import threading
# from pynput import mouse
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Button, Controller
# pynput.keyboard is used to watch events of 
# keyboard for start and stop of auto-clicker
# from pynput.keyboard import KeyCode
  
  
# four variables are created to 
# control the auto-clicker
delay = 0.001
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = Button.x2
stop_key = Button.x2
  
# threading.Thread is used 
# to control clicks
class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    
  # delay and button is passed in class 
  # to check execution of auto-clicker
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True
  
    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True
  
    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False
  
    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False
  
    # method to check and run loop until 
    # it is true another loop will check 
    # if it is set to true or not, 
    # for mouse click it set to button 
    # and delay.
    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
            time.sleep(0.1)
  
  
# instance of mouse controller is created
mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()
  
  
# on_click method takes 
# key as argument
def on_click(key):
    
  # start_stop_key will stop clicking 
  # if running flag is set to true
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
              
    # here exit method is called and when 
    # key is pressed it terminates auto clicker
    elif key == stop_key:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop()
  
  
with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I'm just not sure what I am missing at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like you edited a use of a keyboard Listener's `on_press()` into a use of a mouse Listener's `on_click()` - but you didn't change the parameter list, which is entirely different between the two methods.  I don't think your approach is going to work anyway - if your autoclicking is stopped by a mouse click, would it not immediately stop itself?

Comment: I want to use Button.x2, which is a button on the side of my mouse, to start and stop the autoclicker. While the autoclicker is running, though, it will be pressing the Button.left which is the left mouse button. The error "TypeError: on_click() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given" makes me think I'm passing too much to the on_click function but not sure how it's happening.

Comment: Ok, that might work with a different mouse button to control the autoclicker.  *You're* not calling `on_click()` yourself, the Listener is, and it's calling the function with four parameters - you need to change the parameter list to accept those parameters, rather than the one parameter that the keyboard Listener would pass.